# Reactor - Load all pages of a paginated API

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, reactor

I'm wondering about Reactor and paginated HTTP APIs. I have a `private fun getPage(pageNumber: Int): Mono<SomePaginatedResouce>`. The resource has a "numberOfPages" field, and I'd like to obtain all the pages.

The first try is as follows:

```
getPage(1)
    .map { it.numberOfPages }
    .flatMapMany { Flux.range(1, it) }
    .flatMap { getPage(it) }
```

It works and gets my data. However, I want to avoid requesting the first page twice. So I'm thinking:

```
getPage(1)
    .expand { it ->
        if (it.isFirst) {
            // If it is the first page, load the rest of the pages
            Flux.range(2, it.numberOfPages)
                    .flatMap { getPage(it) }
        } else {
            // If it is a subsequent page, don't load anything
            Flux.empty()
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this, rather than using `expand` and introducing a special flag in my resources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
getPage(1).flatMapMany(
        it -> Flux.concat(Mono.just(it), Flux.range(2, it.numberOfPages - 1).flatMap(this::getPage))
);
```

Afraid it's Java rather than Kotlin, but that should be pretty trivial to translate.

(Remember that `Flux.range()` works on "start" and "count" parameters, not "first index" and "last index".)

Comment: Ah yes, that looks good, thank you. Thanks for the reminder of Flux.range, totally missed that. You could then do away with the "if" condition, right ? Since if `numberOfPages == 1`, then `Flux.range(2, 0)` would be an empty Flux.

I like your solution since I don't need to bother with "isFirst". Is it more "reactor-idiomatic"  than using expand ?

Comment: @Kehrlann Doh, of course - I explained `Flux.range()` correctly then forgot to imply the thinking to the answer! That's now updated.

Comment: @Kehrlann Sorry, missed the second point. Yes, in my experience `expand()` is a relatively rare operator, and mapping on `Flux.range()` is more normal. That's not to say the former is wrong at all, or even that the state of play will stay that way (reactor is still quite a niche area) - that's just my experience as things stand at the moment.